# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, umbraco, plesk

I've tried with Gmail (tried activating less secure apps, 2 steps verification and apps password, zone time, etc..).
Also, I tried sending emails with outlook and I'm having the same error.

In the console, I get the followed error: POST 500

Notes:

- I don't have access to the Server.
- This is working on my Local.
- The website uses Plesk.
- The Gmail code was working before, but after changing the password is not working (we activated less security apps).
- In Gmail code, I've tried different ports.

Code:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress(model.EmailAddress);
message.To.Add("email@gmail.com");
message.Subject = string.Format("Mensaje de {0} ({1}) - {2}", model.FirstName, model.EmailAddress, model.Subject);
message.Body = model.Message;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password");
client.Send(message);

/*
MailMessage mc = new MailMessage(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), "email@hotmail.com");
mc.Subject = string.Format("Mensaje de {0} ({1}) - {2}", model.FirstName, model.EmailAddress, model.Subject);
mc.Body = model.Message;
mc.IsBodyHtml = false;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
smtp.Timeout = 1000000;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = nc;
smtp.Send(mc);
        */
```

Comment: Maybe you should check your server firewall. I advice you to host on Azure instead of other kind of solutions. Just to avoid sysadmin challenges instead of software / business challenges

Comment: I did it, I disabled all the rules on the firewall and also the firewall, and still not working (I activated the rules again once I tested it)

Comment: Try other email provider, just to discard that is something special with Gmail SMTP

Comment: Hi Alberto, I already tried with Outlook and still the same problem.

Comment: Could you confirm that you worked on that? https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213376509